# cannot implicitly convert type string to system.datetime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am trying to convert dateTime into string format such as dd-MM-yy,but while trying to convert into string format i have get an compile time error.

```
public List<ExpertTrckerReportTO> SetFeatureEventDetails(DateTime d1, DateTime currentDate, string eventName, List<ExpertTrckerReportTO> lst)
{
    ExpertTrckerReportTO _expertTrckerReportTO = new ExpertTrckerReportTO();

    _expertTrckerReportTO.DaysUntilFutureEvent = (d1 - currentDate).Days;
    _expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventName = eventName;
    string format = "dd-MM-yy";           
        _expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventDate = d1.ToString(format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);           
    lst.Add(_expertTrckerReportTO);

    return lst;
}
```

the below line through the error

```
_expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventDate = d1.ToString(format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can any one help me me with the syntax how to solve the error.

Comment: `FutureEventDate` is also a DateTime field.

Answer (score 3):

That happend because `_expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventDate` is DateTime. You cannot implicitly convert `d1.ToString(format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` (string) to DateTime

May be you want

```
_expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventDate = d1
```

Sorry. Post as answer because I haven't enough raiting to comment

Comment: yep that true but i got whole date and time but i want only date

Comment: thats why i provide toString method

Comment: @SamiParkar use `d1.Date`

Comment: thanks for your answer,but still i am not getting date in this particular format{dd-MM-yy}

Comment: Darkhac nailed it. Use _expertTrckerReportTO.FutureEventDate = d1.Date. Sami, a DateTime has no format until you convert it to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateTime.ToString();
```

Hope It's the solution you hoped :)